# Algebraic relation given by a 3x3 determinant

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, determinants

I just encountered a very curious relation in an algebra. A bit simplified, I am working in a (particular) non-commutative algebra, with some relations.

One particular relation is the following:
For (some particular choices of) 
elements $a,b,c,x,y,z$ in the algebra,
the relation is of the form $bz+cx+ay = az+bx+cy$. 
This can be stated as a vanishing 3x3-determinant,

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
a & b & c \\
x & y & z
\end{vmatrix}=0.
$$

We can think of $a,...,z$ as words, and multiplication is simply concatenation. **Has this type of relation been observed/used in some algebras before**? Does it fit into some larger picture?

In my concrete case, this relation does not hold in general, but only for certain particular combinations of $a,b,c,x,y,z$, so examples where there are some restrictions on when the relation applies are also interesting to me.

Comment: What is your definition of the determinant in a non-commutative algebra?

Comment: The formula stated below the determinant. That is, "Sarrus' rule". I am mainly interested in the 3x3 case (as that's what I encountered).

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. The free non-commutative algebra on $\{a,b,c,x,y,z\}$ has as a basis all ordered monomials in the letters. So $bz$ is linearly independent of $cz, ay, az, bx, cy$, ruling out the relation you claim holds. What algebra are we working in? Is your question really: `if this relation holds, what can deduce about related determinants?'

Comment: @MarkWildon I realized that the question was poorly worded, and I hope it is now clarified. Basically, I have a relation given by a 'determinant' where multiplication is non-commutative, and wonder if this type of non-commutative relation has any meaning.

Comment: But your determinant has plenty of non-equivalent ways to be read, unless you specify precisely rules. Formally: you want to choose a lift from the determinant formula from the polynomial algebra in $n^2$ variables to the non-commutative one. Probably you implicitly have such a lift in your mind.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson : I have the feeling it would be easier if you would explain the concrete example you are working with in more details.

Comment: @MarkSapir: No, that is not my question - I consider this as part of the relations which hold. For example, whenever you see the relation $aba=bab$, you might think 'Braid relation!'. I wonder if the determinant relation above gives a similar reaction.

Comment: I was told that this looks a lot like the Yang-Baxter relation. This seem to fit the broader picture I am looking at.